# Adding a tooltip to a custom CMFCCaptionButton

Tags: mfc

Anyone knows how to add a tooltip to a custom `CMFCCaptionButton` in a `CDocakablePane`/`CMultiPaneFrameWnd` ?

Using
`ON_NOTIFY_EX_RANGE(TTN_NEEDTEXT,0,0xFFFF,OnNeedTipText)`
and
`MyCaptionButton* pBtn = new MyCaptionButton(this);`
`m_lstCaptionButtons.AddHead(pBtn);`
`pBtn->SetMiniFrameButton();`
`m_pToolTip->AddTool( this, LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK, pBtn->GetRect(),2);`
`m_pToolTip->Activate(TRUE);`
does not call the event, but the two other buttons do (close & pin)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I once found is that the TTN_ range of macros aren't implemented /sent properly for both the A and W versions. Are you using an ascii build? If so, try catching the TTN_NEEDTEXTA and TTN_NEEDTEXTW messages directly.

Secondly, try using spy++ to see if the TTN_NEEDTEXT message is send to the parent windows of the window you're expecting it to end up at. I remember being quite surprised at how these messages were send the last time I implemented this, although I can't remember the details.